# MS Guidelines for Overriding Equals() fails own criteria. Best practice to use instead?

Tags: c#, equality

I was reviewing the Guidelines Microsoft puts out for overriding the Equals operator. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx

they state that:

> The new implementation of Equals should follow all the guarantees of
>   Equals:
>
> - x.Equals(x) returns true.
> - x.Equals (y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).
> - if (x.Equals (y) && y.Equals (z)) returns true, then x.Equals(z) returns true.
> - Successive invocations of x.Equals(y)    return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y    are not modified.
> - x.Equals (null) returns false (for non-nullable value types only.)

They follow that up with examples of a base class and subclass (TwoDPoint and ThreeDPoint, code below) which implement their best practices for overriding this method.

However, **these two example classes fail the "Guarantees of Equals" that were just given**. IE, TwoDPoint.Equals(ThreeDPoint) can return true but ThreeDPoint.Equals(TwoDPoint) will always return false. This fails the 2nd bullet point above.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwoDPoint twoDPoint = new TwoDPoint(1, 2);
        ThreeDPoint threeDPoint = new ThreeDPoint(1, 2, 3);

        //this will assert because twoDPoint.Equals(threeDPoint) == true 
        //but, threeDPoint.Equals(twoDPoint) == false
        AssertMicrosoftEqualsGuidelines(twoDPoint, threeDPoint, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will Assert() if any of microsofts rules for Equals overriding fail.
    /// NOTE, x and y can not be null.
    /// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx
    /// </summary>
    static void AssertMicrosoftEqualsGuidelines(object x, object y, object z)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(x.Equals(x), "FAILED x.Equals(x) returns true.");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(x.Equals(y) == y.Equals(x), "FAILED x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).");

        if(x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(x.Equals(z), "FAILED Successive invocations of x. Equals (y) return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y are not modified.");
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(x.Equals(y) == x.Equals(y) == x.Equals(y) == x.Equals(y), "Successive invocations of x. Equals (y) return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y are not modified.");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(x.Equals(null) == false, "x.Equals (null) returns false");
    }
}

class TwoDPoint : System.Object
{
    public readonly int x, y;

    public TwoDPoint(int x, int y)  //constructor
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
        TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }

    public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return x ^ y;
    }
}

class ThreeDPoint : TwoDPoint
{
    public readonly int z;

    public ThreeDPoint(int x, int y, int z)
        : base(x, y)
    {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter cannot be cast to ThreeDPoint return false:
        ThreeDPoint p = obj as ThreeDPoint;
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return base.Equals(obj) && z == p.z;
    }

    public bool Equals(ThreeDPoint p)
    {
        // Return true if the fields match:
        return base.Equals((TwoDPoint)p) && z == p.z;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode() ^ z;
    }
}
```

So are the guidelines for the "guarantees of equals" wrong? Should people overriding equals also check that the types of the two objects are the same? IE

```
if(GetType() != obj.GetType()){return false;} //include in Equals()?
```

Really, I guess it comes down to, is it considered "ok" to have a baseclass equals() method return true for a subclass if all of the baseclass fields match? This makes sense from the baseclass's perspective IMHO, however, you do end up breaking rule #2 above. What would the impact be of breaking that rule be on ojects such as dictionary's and hashsets etc. Would you just be asking for subtle bugs?

Comment: I've seen the implementation both ways. Answer is it depends.

Comment: You should not use inheritance just for code reuse purpose.

Comment: Someome has pointed this out in the article comments, and the team seems to have responded `This topic is no longer in the current library, and it was replaced long enough ago that I can no longer update it.`

Answer (score 3):

The examples are bad. You'll see this quite often in MSDN - they usually focus on one thing only, ignoring everything else.

Equality is a tricky concept, and it doesn't fit well with inheritance (you'll see the "doesn't fit well with inheritance" rather often - inheritance is... tricky). As noted, there's two main ways of thinking about equality - value equality, and reference equality. The fun part is, the two may or may not overlap.

Reference equality is the simpler kind. It fits well with inheritance, since it doesn't do any interpretation of the objects you're comparing - either the reference is the same, or it isn't. All the guidelines apply well for reference equality.

Value equality is much more complicated, and more importantly, there's some overlap between equality and identity.

Talking strict value equality, it just doesn't work with inheritance, period. It's very easy to implement strict value equality with structs, especially if you follow all the guidelines for struct design. There's no inheritance and ideally, your structs are immutable. The same applies to anonymous types - that's why they can afford to have value equality by default; the limitations make it rather simple.

Two objects simply cannot be strictly equal if they are not of the same type. So indeed, for best effects, you shouldn't ever allow `myClass.Equals(subclass)` or the other way around. This is very important for other code that depends on the correct behaviour of `Equals` (e.g. hashsets).

Since there's cases where it's practical to do something else than strict equality, people write many different kinds of comparison methods. Maybe you care about the ID of the object, but not the other fields - the identity. Maybe you want to see if you need to update an object in the database. Some people override the `Equals` method to provide this functionality, and that's simply wrong. If you have a problem like this, make your own method. It's not like .NET limits you in how many methods or interfaces a class can have :)

You can see how absurd the notion is when you look at the types MSDN uses for this example. Those shouldn't be subclasses in the first place! No 3D point can ever be equal to a 2D point, and a 3D point can never be a *replacement* for a 2D point. This doesn't just violate the Equals guidelines, it violates common object-design practices. It's using inheritance for code reuse, and that's not a good approach to object design. A subclass should always be a valid replacement for its ancestor class, which clearly isn't the case here.

People make mistakes. The ones who write MSDN do that as well. You'll find that the .NET BCL has plenty of things that are just wrong - perhaps they made sense at one point, perhaps the practices changed, or the guys who designed them just didn't get it right. This happens all the time, and you must be prepared for it. Practices are not written in stone, and they are always very contextual - you must understand the reasonings so that you can pick whether they make sense for a given scenario or not. And now ask yourself, do you want your hashset class to think that a 2D point is equal to a 3D point? Imagine code like this:

```
var set = new HashSet<2DPoint>();
set.Add(new 2DPoint(3, 3));
set.Add(new 3DPoint(3, 3, 0));
```

Should the second `Add` fail? What if it's an add or update method, and while you think you added a 3DPoint, you actually just kept the old 2DPoint that's "equal"? How happy will your code be about getting a 2DPoint instead of a 3DPoint?

If you need anything that isn't strict value equality or reference equality... just add your own method. Or your own interface. But don't just "reuse" `Equals` just because it's already there - it's interface is pretty clear, and you're violating that. It's little different from implementing `IComparable<T>` in a way that doesn't conform to `IComparable<T>` - it just looks "different", because the interface is implicit. But it's still an interface you must conform to. Reusing interfaces just because they have similar method signatures to what you want is just bad. And I've been guilty of that in the past as well - using the `ThreadStart` delegate whenever a `void ()` delegate was needed (`Action`, on the other hand, is perfectly fine - you're not violating the interface of "do some action that returns nothing and takes no arguments").

Answer (score 2):

I think this is only a concept problem. Somehow they constructed a 3D point by inheriting from a 2D point, which makes no logical sense. If we take at base value (pun intended) that a 3D point is a 2D point translated into another dimension, then a 3D point is the same no matter its height from a two dimensional point of view.

That being said, you need to think if inside your own code the inheritance model really makes sense as well as where you are comparing two instances. In the example case, probably another piece of code, like an assertion, should have thrown an exception when 2D and 3D objects were compared for equality.

Let me give you a real life example. You see two Mercedes Benz cars of the same model and you ask yourself "are these cars the same?" and the answer is yes. Then you realize that one of them has a different color than the other and you realize that the answer is no. Equality is not absolute, it depends on your perspective. And now officially this became a philosophical answer.

Comment: I think your real life example is misleading - sure, what we mean by "equality" is subjective. But what the `object.Equals` method means *isn't* subjective - it's a defined contract that lots of code depends on. If you need a different kind of equality... well, just go ahead and make your own method. The rest of the answer is spot-on :)

Comment: The contract is not so strict. The default Equals is a reference equality for objects, but in cases such as these we suddenly override that behaviour to say that two completely different instances are equal because their coordinates in a 2D space are the same. For me this is a bigger perversion of the concept of equality than just adding more properties to check.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at it the wrong way. You're not comparing apples to apples when you say that if 2dpoint.Equals(3dPoint) is true then 3dpoint.Equals(2dpoint) must also be true.

If 2dpoint1.Equals(2dpoint2) then 2dpoint2.Equals(2dpoint1) must also be equal. And 3dpoint1.Equals(3dpoint2) then 3dpoint2.Equals(3dpoint1) must also be equal.

So it should be, "When comparing 2 instances of the same class ..."

Also note that in the Microsoft example you wouldn't be able to use my3DPoint.Equals(my2DPoint) since there's no Equals method that takes a 2D point in the 3D point class.

We use very similar classes in our application which deals with 3D data. We do use my2DPoint.Equals(my3DPoint) to test if points align in the X, Y plane but would never use my3DPoint.Equals(my2DPoint) because that would imply that I want a 3D comparison which isn't possible with a 2D point.